Delete all custom Domain certificates AppService
I created a form where I can add but also delete a custom domain and certificate.
I delete the domain in the following way:
var hostBinding = hostnameBindings.Get(_customDomain);
if (hostBinding != null)
{
    SiteHostNameBindingResource siteHostNameBinding = hostBinding.Value;
    await siteHostNameBinding.DeleteAsync(WaitUntil.Completed);
}

But I don't know how to delete the certificate:
AppCertificateCollection certcollection = _resourceGroupResource.GetAppCertificates();

If I know the name of the certificate, I can do it like this:
var certificate = certcollection.Exists("name");
certificate.Delete();


What is the version of your app?

I work in Blazor wit Azure SDK

You can run a for wach loop for each app service name and use the same certificate.Delete(); .
`

try out the c# code below below. it will get all resources in the RG and see if the resource is a cert. If it is a cert, you can invoke the DeleteAsync() to delete the cert. MSFT documentation here for AppCertificateResource.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.resourcemanager.appservice.appcertificateresource?view=azure-dotnet
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.ResourceManager;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Resources;
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Certificates;
using Azure.ResourceManager.AppService;

public class AzureResourceGroupExample
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string subscriptionId = "xxxx";
        string resourceGroupName = "rg-xxx";

        ArmClient armClient = new ArmClient(new DefaultAzureCredential());
        ResourceIdentifier subscriptionResourceId = new ResourceIdentifier($"/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}");
        SubscriptionResource subscription = armClient.GetSubscriptionResource(subscriptionResourceId);
        ResourceGroupResource _resourceGroupResource = await subscription.GetResourceGroupAsync(resourceGroupName);
        Console.WriteLine($"Resource group retrieved: {_resourceGroupResource.Data.Name}");

        await foreach (var resource in _resourceGroupResource.GetGenericResourcesAsync())
        {
            if (resource.Data.ResourceType == "Microsoft.Web/certificates")
            {
                var certificateResource = await _resourceGroupResource.GetAppCertificateAsync(resource.Data.Name);
                Console.WriteLine($"- Certificate Resource: {certificateResource.Value.Id}");
                // certificateResource.Value.DeleteAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"- Resource: {resource.Data.Name}, Type: {resource.Data.ResourceType}");
            }
        }

    }
}

